# Multiple transactions lines to base table SAS

Tags: sas, radix

I am new to sas and are trying to handle some customer data, and I'm not really sure how to do this. 
What I have:

```
data transactions;                      
input ID $  Week Segment $ Average Freq;       
datalines;            
1 1 Sports 500 2
1 1 PC 400 3
1 2 Sports 350 3
1 2 PC 550 3
2 1 Sports 650 2
2 1 PC 700 3
2 2 Sports 720 3
2 2 PC 250 3
;                                    
run;
```

What I want:

```
data transactions2;
input ID Week1_Sports_Average Week1_PC_Average Week1_Sports_Freq 
Week1_PC_Freq
Week2_Sports_Average Week2_PC_Average Week2_Sports_Freq Week2_PC_Freq;
datalines;
1 500 400 2 3 350 550 3 3 
2 650 700 2 3 720 250 3 3
;
run;
```

The only thing I got so far is this:

```
 Data transactions3;
 SET transactions;
 if week=1 and Segment="Sports" then DO; 
 Week1_Sports_Freq=Freq; 
 Week1_Sports_Average=Average;
 END;
 else DO;
 Week1_Sports_Freq=0; 
 Week1_Sports_Average=0;
 END;
 run;
```

This will be way too much work as I have a lot of weeks and more variables than just freq/avg.

Really hoping for some tips are, as I'm stucked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PROC TRANSPOSE to create that structure. But you need to use it twice since your original dataset is not fully normalized.

The first PROC TRANSPOSE will get the AVERAGE and FREQ readings onto separate rows.

```
proc transpose data=transactions out=tall ;
  by id week segment notsorted;
  var average freq ;
run;
```

If you don't mind having the variables named slightly differently than in your proposed solution you can just use another proc transpose to create one observation per ID.

```
proc transpose data=tall out=want delim=_;
  by id;
  id segment _name_ week ;
  var col1 ;
run;
```

If you want the exact names you had before you could add data step to first create a variable you could use in the ID statement of the PROC transpose.

```
data tall ;
  set tall ;
  length new_name $32 ;
  new_name = catx('_',cats('WEEK',week),segment,_name_);
run;
proc transpose data=tall out=want ;
  by id;
  id new_name;
  var col1 ;
run;
```

Note that it is easier in SAS when you have a numbered series of variable if the number appears at the end of the name.  Then you can use a variable list. So instead of WEEK1_AVERAGE, WEEK2_AVERAGE, ... you would use WEEK_AVERAGE_1, WEEK_AVERAGE_2, ... So that you could use a variable list like `WEEK_AVERAGE_1 - WEEK_AVERAGE_5` in your SAS code.